# Algorithmic "for" and "end for" don't not begin new line

Tags: algorithmic

I'm using a for loop in an algorithmic environment as follows:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{data collection}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Synthesised data}{\textit{input:} control docs}
    \Procedure{Keywords extraction}{\textit{input:} control docs}
         \For{doc in control docs}
            extract keywords from doc and add to keywords set
         \EndFor
         remove duplicated keywords from keywords set
         export keywords to a $txt$ file for manual filtration 
    \EndProcedure
    \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

and the output appears as the picture 
[image]

Any help!

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I'm missing `\State` at the beginning of each statement, so the code should be like that:

```
\Procedure{Keywords extraction}{\textit{input:} control docs}
         \For{doc in control docs}
            \State get indexed keywords from doc meta-data and add to keywords set
         \EndFor
         \State remove duplicate keywords from keywords set
         \State export keywords to a $txt$ file for manual filtration 
    \EndProcedure
```

Comment: You could expand your answer to include a full compilable example that new users can try out.